# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error, 'logits shape and labels shape must have the same dimension'

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to solve an aspect based sentiment analysis problem.

I have constructed an NN architecture which I believe is logical but had problems in finding the right loss function. or maybe my architecture is wrong and you may help me with that. but I mainly write here for the error that my code has.  Here is the set up.

I have a training set of 980 rows which has different (turkish) sentences in each line. It also contains labels as one or more aspects for each sentence and the sentiments for each of these aspects. so one sentence can have more than one aspect.

There are 910 different aspects in the training set.

I use lstm architecture by devising the problem as a multi label multi class problem.
for each sentence input, there will be 910 neurons at the output layer for each aspect and the nuerons will have 4 different classes(1 if the sentiment is positive 2 if negative 3 if neutral and 0 if the aspect doesnt exist for this sentence)

so it esssentially looks like a softmax -categorical cross entropy problem
but the problem is the classes are not binary. they can take 4 different values.

that is why a softmax activation function with categorical cross entropy as loss does not work.

so I use softmax as activation and sparsecategoricalentropy as loss function. but it raises an error.

for reference here is my code for the model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 100, input_length=max_sequence_length))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))

model.add(Dense(512, activation=‘relu’))

model.add(Dense(512, activation=‘relu’))

model.add(Dense(910, activation=‘softmax’))

model.compile(loss=‘SparseCategoricalCrossentropy’, optimizer=‘adam’, metrics=[‘categorical_accuracy’])

batch_size = 64

epochs = 100

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=epochs)
```

when I run the model it gives the following error

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,910] and labels shape [58240]
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_135707]
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11542]

the interesting thing is that when I use ‘categoricalcrossentropy’ it does not raise error but when I change it to sparsecategoricalentropy, it raises the above error. It says 'logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,910] and labels shape [58240]'
I have no idea where 58240 comes from.
what do you guys think?

thank you in advance for your help,

mehmet

Comment: Hi @mehmet, Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the issue. It seems there is data preprocessing issue. You have only 4 classes to predict as sentiment analysis, so please mention 4 in the last dense layer. Please have a look at this similar model [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification)  for your reference.